# ¿Cómo elegir el mismo producto pero con diferentes adicionales usando ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando un producto tenga adicionales poder elegir en dos ocasiones ese mismo producto pero con diferentes adicionales o es su defecto sin ellos, me ocurre que como uso *ReactJS*, me detecta que tengo dos hijos iguales porque como lo traigo de una *API* obviamente cuando escojo dos veces el producto me lanza el mismo *key*, la pregunta final es la siguiente

¿Cómo modificar la variable *quantity* sin alterar todos los productos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
const modifyQuantity = (product_id, qty) => {
    const newCart = carrito.map(i => {
        if (i.product_id === product_id) {
            return { ...i, quantity: i.quantity + qty }
        }
        return i;
    })
    const cartWithoutZeros = newCart.filter(i => i.quantity !== 0)
    saveCarrito(cartWithoutZeros)
}
```

Comment: Entonces tu propósito es tener en tu interface, un registro de "Hamburguesa con carne" y la cantidad "2", en vez de tener 2 registros listados de "Hamburguesa con carne", saludos

Comment: Podrías crear un arreglo e ir manejando el mismo producto con el mismo id, pero con distinto índice.

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el código del método `carOrdering` o los métodos involucrados en pintar el carrito? Puede que el problema se encuentre al seleccionar un alimento de la lista de la derecha e insertarlo en el carrito.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUCIONADO:** Lo que hice fue que en el componente de *ItemCarrito* que era el de mostrar ítem en el carro de compra, le agregue un id random con una librería en este caso use *uuidv4* con esto ya no tenia el problema de que los hijos tuvieran el mismo key y poder manipular la cantidad en vez del id del producto seria con el id que le asigna dicha librería, gracias a todos. Dejo el código.

Es decir que *onclick* que uso para pintar el componente y pasarle el *state* le concateno `const ID = uuid()`, esto me dejará el id random y único, cuando ya se lo paso al componente uso ese id para el key y para la función que cambia el *quantity* de cada producto.

```
const modifyQuantity = (pruebaid, qty) => {
    const newCart = carrito.map(i => {
        if (i.pruebaid === pruebaid) {
            return { ...i, quantity: i.quantity + qty }
        }
        return i;
    })
    const cartWithoutZeros = newCart.filter(i => i.quantity !== 0)
    saveCarrito(cartWithoutZeros)
}
```